# Aria-live not working when focus put on another field

Tags: wai-aria

I am writing a very simple SPA application that has a single read-only 'output' field, followed by a single input field. When the user types an input command and hits enter, the JavaScript writes text into the output field. I want the screen reader to read this output straight away without the user having to navigate to the output field, so I added aria-live, thus:

```
<div>
    <div class="output" aria-live="polite">{{myViewModel.output}}</div>
    <input type="text" myAngularDirective />
</div>
```

In the first iteration this worked exactly as I wanted.  However, some of the commands change the Url (though rendered using the same view) and I wanted to ensure that the focus is left on the input field, and in most cases, the input field is cleared for the next command.  When I add code either to focus on the input, or modify it, the output still renders fine on the screen but is no longer read out by the screen reader.

I've tried:

- Changing (in the JavaScript) the order of writing the output and
  clearing/focussing on the input
- Upping the aria-live to 'assertive'
- Adding aria-live to the input also (not sure why I thought that would
  help)
- Moving the aria-live from the output field to the surrounding    div

None has made a difference.  If I remove the focus/clear logic, all works well again.  There is some subtlety about how aria-live works that I am missing: any help appreciated.

Comment: My app is now working as I wish, but unfortunately it is not clear to me exactly which of many changes fixed it. It might well have been a different combination or ordering of the things I mentioned in the original post!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question without a reproducible code sample, and you haven't mentioned which browser and screen reader combination you were testing with. But, it may be that with your focus logic is overriding the `aria-live="polite"` setting. For example, when the page is updated, the `aria-live` announcement is queued (because `aria-live="polite" is the least intrusive setting), but when the keyboard focus is then intercepted to keep focus in the` `, this overrides the announcement.